# How to properly use FontAwesome in a Vue project in 2020?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, font-awesome

I would like to use some FontAwesome fonts in a Vue 2.5 project (running with Laravel). According to the manual the best way if I don't want to use CDN and make my app run offline is to add this to my `app.js`:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faUserSecret } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

library.add(faUserSecret)

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
```

Then in my Vue component (`.vue`) I have to use this:

```
<font-awesome-icon icon="user-secret" />
```

So each time I want to use a new icon I have to:

1. Go to https://fontawesome.com/icons
2. Check the `free` button
3. Search for an icon
4. Go to the detail
5. Copy the link i.e. `<i class="far fa-eye"></i>`
6. Go to my `app.js` (or in my case my `fontawesome.js`) and add:

   ```
   import { faUserSecret, faEye } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

   library.add(faUserSecret)
   library.add(faEye)
   ```
7. Go to my Vue component and add `<font-awesome-icon icon="eye" />` wherever I want to

Is this process optimum and minimal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It's a heavy process I admit, but it has benefits for performance.

Everything's explained on the [library's readme](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome#why-use-the-concept-of-a-library):

> **Why use the concept of a library?**
> Explicitly selecting icons offer the advantage of only bundling the icons that you use in your final bundled file. This allows us to subset Font Awesome's thousands of icons to just the small number that are normally used.

If you don't mind having a bundle including unused icons, you can import everything as so:

```
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

library.add(fab)
```

Take the time to read the entire readme, I know it's long but it's worth it!

Comment: I agree, but it would be some kind of scaffolding to automatically add to the library all the used icons, isn’t?

Comment: It's not easily possible sadly. But maybe with NuxtJS framework you could, as it has an option to auto import all used components.